# Не получается составить регулярку на исключение папок

Tags: javascript, юнит-тесты, jest

Предварительно [документация](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testpathignorepatterns-array-string).

Что надо прописать в `testPathIgnorePatterns` вместо **app-registry**, чтобы игнорировались папки с **любым** именем, на конце у которых есть **_off**?

Как только не пробовал уже:

`<rootDir>/test/jest/__tests__/pact/services/*_off/`

`<rootDir>/test/jest/__tests__/pact/services/*_off/*`

`<rootDir>/test/jest/__tests__/pact/**/*_off/`

`<rootDir>/test/jest/__tests__/pact/**/*_off/*`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Нужно чтоб в выборку попали только папки без _off (выделил зеленым на картинке).

P.P.S. Если явно указать имя - работает. Но если у меня таких папок 100 шт? О_о

Comment: попробуйте так: `<rootDir>/test/jest/__tests__/pact/(?:.+?)_off`

Comment: `<rootDir>/test/jest/__tests__/pact/**/*off$`

Comment: **And** - спасибо! так сработало

**AlexSazonov** - тоже благодарю за помощь, но этот вариант не сработал

Comment: даже если бы вариант @AlexSazonov сработал, то он бы охватывал бы все окончания на `off` не зависимо от нужных шаблонов конкретных папок и вы бы еще с ним намучились бы.